# How can I add a jQuery calendar in Ninja Form Builder in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, calendar, ninja-forms

I need help to use this jQuery Calendar (https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clean-Data-Timepicker-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-3/) in Ninja Form Builder in WordPres.

Please help me to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ninja form give you the option how you can extend the field with datepicker http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/datepicker/ check this.